# how do arithmetic operators work with addresses in c?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main(void){
   int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   printf("%p\t%p\t%d\n",arr,arr+1,(arr+1)-arr);
   return 0;
 }
```

output :

```
  0x7ffe583f4ba0    0x7ffe583f4ba4  1
```

why is the difference 1? Shouldn't it be 4.

Comment: Why shouldn't what be 4?

Comment: The difference is in units of what the pointer is pointing to. In your case in units of `sizeof *arr`.

Comment: `arr + 1 - arr` = `arr - arr + 1` = `0 - 1`, why would that be any different :?

Comment: Sidenote: the difference between two pointers yields a `ptrdiff_t`, not an `int`. Your conversion type specifier invokes undefined behaviour. And why do you assume `sizeof(int) == 4`?

Comment: @toohonestforthissite The output of the two `%p` values shared by the OP have a difference of 4

Comment: @GovindParmar: Even this does not imply what I wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think this expression `(arr+1)-arr` as

```
0x7ffe583f4ba0 + 1 - 0x7ffe583f4ba0
```

it will give `1`.

When you subtract two pointers pointing to the same array then it gives the number of elements between those pointers.
By the same logic, if you increment a pointer to an array of `int` by 1 then it will point to it's next element (one unit) and not to the next `sizeof(int)` element.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform pointer arithmetic with `+` and `-` the size of the type pointed to is taken into account:

```
int main() {
    int arr[2] = { 1, 2 };
    int *p = arr;
    printf("%p -> %d\n", (void *)p, *p);
    p++;
    printf("%p -> %d\n", (void *)p, *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0115FCCC -> 1
0115FCD0 -> 2
```